# Proxy Error - I don't think I am running a proxy

Tags: php, laravel, apache, proxy

I have the following error, when I try to execute a request on my PHP/Laravel/Apache server which takes a long time to execute. As far as I know I am not running a proxy...? I can't seem to find a way to resolve this error. I also can't find anything about this error in the Apache logs. My PHP code is just running a large request against Amazon's MWS web service, but I can't tell where the error is originating from. The error seems to occur after 300 seconds, and I have tried adjusting the Timeout variable in the apache.conf but it didn't change anything.

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /api/test.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Comment: See if anything in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406845 helps

Comment: @Scuzzy no luck, same error

Comment: @Aaron, it's a bit late but did you find solution for this issue?